# JavaScript truthiness in boolean to numbers comparison

Tags: javascript, string, boolean

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to learn it from internet resources. While I'm aware that there will plenty of cr*p material, one thing most people seemed to agree is the truthiness of things in JS (just to give a example go [here](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript))

Now I found this odd thing in my experiments:

`(true == 2)` is `false`. why?

As far as I know, `2` is a non zero *number*, so it should be evaluated as `true`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because when either operand of an equality operator is a number, in nearly all cases the other operand is converted to a number and then the result is compared. So you're ending up comparing `1` (converted from `true`) with `2`, not `true` with `true`. The only exceptions to that rule are `null`, `undefined`, and objects whose *default value* (see off-topic below) is `null` or `undefined`; comparing a number to those returns `false` (even though `Number(null)` is `0`; don't ask).

Details in [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), Section 11.9.3: *"The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm"*. This was the text of that section as of ES 5.1, but that link is to the currently editor's draft (which is what each year's snapshot specification is based on) and there have been several :

> The comparison *x* == *y*, where *x* and *y* are values, produces **true** or **false**. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. If [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*x*) is the same as [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*y*), then
>
>    1. Return the result of performing [Strict Equality Comparison](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) *x* === *y*.
> 2. If *x* is **null** and *y* is **undefined**, return **true**.
> 3. If *x* is **undefined** and *y* is **null**, return **true**.
>   NOTE: This step is replaced in section
>   [B.3.7.2](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-IsHTMLDDA-internal-slot-aec)
>   .
> 4. If [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*x*) is Number and [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*y*) is String, return the result of the comparison *x* == ! [ToNumber](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber)(*y*).
> 5. If [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*x*) is String and [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*y*) is Number, return the result of the comparison ! [ToNumber](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber)(*x*) == *y*.
> 6. If [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*x*) is BigInt and [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*y*) is String, then
>
>    1. Let *n* be ! [StringToBigInt](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-stringtobigint)(*y*).
>    2. If *n* is **NaN**, return **false**.
>    3. Return the result of the comparison *x* == *n*.
> 7. If [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*x*) is String and [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*y*) is BigInt, return the result of the comparison *y* == *x*.
> 8. If [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*x*) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ! [ToNumber](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber)(*x*) == *y*.
> 9. If [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*y*) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison *x* == ! [ToNumber](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber)(*y*).
> 10. If [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*x*) is either String, Number, BigInt, or Symbol and [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*y*) is Object, return the result of the comparison *x* == ? [ToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive)(*y*).
> 11. If [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*x*) is Object and [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*y*) is either String, Number, BigInt, or Symbol, return the result of the comparison ? [ToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive)(*x*) == *y*.
> 12. If [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*x*) is BigInt and [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*y*) is Number, or if [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*x*) is Number and [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*y*) is BigInt, then
>
>     1. If *x* or *y* are any of **NaN**, **+∞**, or **-∞**, return **false**.
>     2. If [ℝ](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#%E2%84%9D)(*x*) = [ℝ](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#%E2%84%9D)(*y*), return **true**; otherwise return **false**.
> 13. Return **false**.

***Note:** The `!`s in the above are **not** negations, they indicate that the following abstract operation never results in an *abrupt completion*. Details in [this article about reading the spec](https://timothygu.me/es-howto/#completion-records-and-shorthands).*

If you wanted to check that they were both truthy or both falsy, you could use the bang (`!`) or double-bang (`!!`) idiom to coerce them both to booleans:

```
var a = true,
    b = 2;
alert(a == b);     // "false", 1 !== 2
alert(!!a == !!b); // "true", true === true
alert(!a == !b);   // "true", false === false
a = false;
b = 0;
alert(a == b);     // "true", 0 === 0
alert(!!a == !!b); // "true", false === false
alert(!a == !b);   // "true", true === true
```

...but usually using `==` or `!=` with booleans isn't ideal. But it does come up.

I tend to use the double-bang, but in JavaScript there's no reason to over the bang. (There's an argument for the double over the single in some other languages, though it's a weak one related to consistency with `if (!!x)`. In JavaScript you never need the double-bang in the `if (x)` case, so...)

---

(Off-topic: The default value of most JavaScript objects is a string, though frequently one like "[object Object]" that ends up being `NaN` if you convert it to a number; but constructor functions can override that behavior via `valueOf` and `toString`. The default value of host objects is up to the host environment.)

Answer (score 3):

The boolean `true` constant is promoted to a number, that being 1.

Answer (score 1):

With non-strict comparison (`==`) if the operands are not of the same type, they will be casted/coerced and strictly compared, with first preference being to numbers if either operand is a number or boolean ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)).

So `true == 2` evaluates to `Number(true) === 2` which is `1 === 2`, which is false.

Of course you can always force things to compare as you want them to, which is explicit and can solve hard-to-find problems later on:

`true === Boolean(2)` is true.