# How exactly does JavaScipt's data-type convertion work for "==" operator?

Tags: javascript, equality, type-conversion

I've recently noticed something strange when I used `if( ... == true)` in JavaScript. The `==` operator should attempt to convert the given data-types to be the same. But some cases don't appear to do that as we would expect:

```
if ( 42 == true ) // false ( Only 1 is true )
if ( "Hello World" == true ) // false ( false for any string )
```

Although if I convert them myself doing `!!` to both `42` and `"someString"` turn out to be `true`:

```
if ( !!42 === true ) // Shows that 42 cast to a boolean is true.
if ( !!"Hello World" === true ) // Same for strings
```

Note if I switch this around `if( true == ... )` the results are the same. I'm wondering exactly what is going on here, why the `==` is converting these items oddly when they indeed convert into `true`. How is JavaScript trying to convert these items? Is it trying to convert the booleans to a `number` or `string` instead?

My main question would be exactly how does the JavaScript equals operator ( `==` ) work when attempting to convert different data-types to be the same in an expression, when a boolean is in the expression in this case?

**Edit:** I want to note that while I did use `!!` in my question, it was simply to show that if I convert the given datatypes into Booleans that they do indeed turn out to by true, while when `==` attempts to convert the result is different. This question is in no way asking about what `!!` is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: @AlexK. I know exactly what the `!!` is, that is not the question.

Comment: @Cristy The question is not the difference between `==` and `===`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yes, but in that answers the `==` operator is explained. And you can always find resources online about what each JavaScript engine actually does with it if you are interested.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: @Cristy Yes but I'm not asking what the `==` is, but how does it act when a data type conversion is done (specifically for booleans). Both those answer do not provide any information on that.

Comment: @self To show converting it to a boolean myself made it `true`. How would you recommend me do it? I don't think doing `if(42)` is clear that I made it into a boolean (at least for people who don't know JS well).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek you shouldn't be using it for comparison anyway, there's no use-case for it.

Comment: @PatsyIssa I don't. Again, I'm asking why is the `==` operator is doing what it's doing in this case. Not that I don't know the difference between them, and what I should use normally.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of either of the questions. +1

Comment: In one of the answers to the question I marked being as duplicate is a table showing all possible cases of conversion done by the `==` operator.

Comment: @Cristy Just because an answer to the question might mention this issue doesn't mean it it's a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of a mix of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6640637/1048572 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/23693089/1048572

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Crockford says: "The rules by which they do that are complicated and unmemorable." The spec defines them all [in section 11.9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) (pointed out by @Oriol in a comment to OP).

For the two cases you provided:

```
if ( 42 == true ) // false ( Only 1 is true )
if ( "Hello World" == true ) // false ( false for any string )
```

In case 1, *y* is a Boolean, so it gets converted to a number (step 7). The number conversion of `true` is 1. So now we're evaluating `42 == 1`. This is obviously false.

In case 2, *y* is again a Boolean, but this time, *x* is a string. Per step 7, *y* is converted to a number, so the comparison is now `"Hello World" == 1`. Per step 5, *x* is now converted to a number. The numerical representation of an arbitrary string is `NaN`. Now `NaN == 1` is being compared. As it says in step 1ai, that's false.

Again, as Crockford said...

Comment: Thanks! I've realised the same thing as you did from section 11.9.3.

Comment: The string `"1"` *is* `== true`. The rules are not totally unmemorable :-)

Answer (score -1):

It appears to me that `==` means "evaluates to the same value".  42 does not equal true because true is being converted to an integer for the comparison, and `42 != 1`.  But if people want to convert 42 to a Boolean, simply do `if (42)`, or you can do the `!!` not not trick.  Most people just do `if (42)`, converting the non-zero, non-empty value to a bool with the parenthetical.

`(x == true)` should only be used when `x` is expected to be either 0 or 1, or true or false.

And I gather you know the difference between `==` and `===` already.

```
(1 == true) // true
(1 === true) // false, because data types aren't converted when using ===
```

For more info on automatic type conversions and assignment shortcuts, I recommend [reading this page](http://www.sitepoint.com/automatic-type-conversion/).  While it doesn't specifically answer your question, it does provide examples illustrating when you should be specific for what you are testing for.