# Why value of variable b is "js" in this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

In the below if condition value of b is js. Can someone please explain how is it getting its value?

```
var b= {
    id: "js",
    toString: function(){
        return "js";
    }
}
if(b=="js"){
    console.log("yes, value of b is js") 
};
```

Comment: I don't get it. Please explain your question a bit

Comment: here b is an object, then why its value is js?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949187/how-exactly-does-javascipts-data-type-convertion-work-for-operator

Comment: [`MDN Object.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *value* of `b` isn't "js", but its string representation is.  The browser calls `.toString()` when it needs to display an object as a string.  For most objects, this will default to something like:

```
[object Object]
```

But since you've implemented `.toString()`, it calls that implementation and displays:

```
js
```

Remove the implementation of `.toString()`, or implement it differently, and see for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript will automatically call the .toString function from an object. Most object have this function but will be something like, object, String, etc.

Your object already has this toString function defined. So you should read it like this:

```
if( b.toString() == "js" ) { }

or

if( b + "" == "js" ){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you've implemented the `toString()`, which is called when doing weak type checking, `==`.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `toString` of object `b` and returning the value `js` this sets b to "js" whenever the b is displayed as a string, http://jsfiddle.net/o1x7rby2/ , http://jsfiddle.net/o1x7rby2/2/
,http://jsfiddle.net/o1x7rby2/1/  you can compare these fiddles

Answer (score 0):

The `b` which is an object, gets typecasted to `String` since it is being compared with a `String` with less strict `==` and that happens by calling of `toString` method, which you've re-implemented to return `"js"` always.

So it is actually what happens is

```
if("js" == "js")
```

But strict opertator `===` will return false, as there is no conversion taking place.