# Why does expression (true == true == true) produce a syntax error?

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, operators, operator-precedence, associativity

**Ruby**:

```rb
true == true == true
```

> syntax error, unexpected tEQ

vs. **JavaScript**:

```js
true == true == true
// => true
```

vs. **C**:

```c
1 == 1 == 1
// => 1
```

Comment: The interesting thing is that it seems to only be the equality operators (`==`, `===`, and `!=`) that do this. Even `<` and `>` parse correctly and then produce a runtime error like you would expect. Plus, the [only](https://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/cse305/RubyBNF.pdf) [sources](http://docs.huihoo.com/ruby/ruby-man-1.4/yacc.html) I can find which claim to have a complete grammar for Ruby would seem to indicate that this syntax is allowable.

Comment: it also works without parenthesis like this, with explicit calling, `true .== true .== true`

Comment: I wonder how many other people incredulously typed the failing code into irb expecting a different result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21060235/2864740 - `==` is listed as **not-associative (A=N)** in the answer, meaning such a `X==Y==Z` production is invalid (associativity is what "adds the implicit parenthesis around operators of the same precedence"). There are many links in the question that might go back to a more "Official Source" that could be cleanly cited. (This question is more of less about a specific subset/application of grammar rules in that question/answer.)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Per the answer above, `<` and friends *are* left-associative.. so should parse (and "work", given valid runtime inputs). I'm not sure what the grammar rational about why `<` would be associative while `==` would not be, although changing that might break lots of expectations..

Comment: So we know that it's intended behavior, as per the provided link. Then it just comes down to why. I can't see a reason to make `==` non-associative but still let `<` and company have associativity.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo The "why" of grammar is often off-topic :) Although, a practical syntax example that works although it would not if there was associativity (ie. non-associativity allows this *other* construct form [by removing other ambiguity]) would be interesting to see.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Association direction, which controls the order of operators having their arguments evaluated, is not defined for the `==` method, same as for `===`, `!=`, `=~` and `<=>` methods as well (all of which have the same precedence and form a separate precedence group exclusively).

[**Documentation**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators)

Thus evaluation order in case of multiple operators from the list mentioned above being chained in a row should be set explicitly via either

- parenthesis `()`:

  ```
  (true == true) == true # => true
  true == (true == true) # => true
  ```
- or dot operator `.` (*can be omitted for the last equality check in a row*):

  ```
  true .== true == true # => true
  ```

Comment: I would be interested in knowing *why*, but I think that's beyond the scope of the question and your answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland maybe because `1 == 1 == 1` would evaluate to `false` in Ruby if `==` was left-associative, which would probably result in several bugs. And it wouldn't make much sense either – the only reasonable values for the 3rd operand are `true` and `false`, i.e. `a == b == true` and `a == b == false` which can be expressed as `a == b` and `a != b`.

Comment: @Stefan: there is only one situation when it can be used like this in a way that it would make sense, though I must say that the example is kinda far-fetched: `==` can be overriden in a custom class  and thus equality check can return something other than just `true` or `false` (for example, `nil`)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think it can be resolved from the language designer's point of view like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9593113c3a4323692676d44f5adaa9c9)

Comment: [javascript-truthiness-in-boolean-to-numbers-comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640637) why we should all stop using 0's or 1's in javascript examples comparing integers with integers or booleans

Answer (score 7):

#### TL;DR The syntax implies that all 3 values are equal this is not what it does in javascript or C, so by ruby giving a syntax error the door is open for this to be implemented in the future.

If I understand the question correctly `value_a == value_b == value_c` should only return true if they are all equal using == as the comparison operater as shown in this method

```
# version 1
def compare_3_values(a, b, c)
  a == b && a == c && b == c
end
```

there is another possible expected outcome though. to implement this as shown in the previous answer:

```
#version 2
def compare_3_values(a, b, c)
  (a == b) == c
end
```

The results are worlds apart.

JavaScript always uses version 2 which is pretty useless as the 3rd item is always being compared against true or false (0 or 1 if the 3rd item is an integer) that's why `false == false == true` returns true.

> The good news is that because ruby gives a syntax error it's the only language that can implement this without breaking everyone's code.
>
> for any other language it would break so much code that even if it were implemented in a later major version there would need to be a flag/setting to turn this on or off for years to come, hence it will never be worthwhile.

Some interesting results in Ruby

```
false .== false == true
=> true

false .== true == false
=> true

true .== false == false
=> true

false .== false == false
=> false

true .== true == false
false
```

And in javascript

```
false == false == true
=> true

false == true == false
=> true

true == false == false
=> true

false == false == false
=> false

true == true == false
=> false
```

**Edit** tested in C as well, acts similar to JavaScript in that it compares the result of the first two values against the third value

Answer (score 4):

The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159938/1757831) is excellent, but just in case it's not completely clear (and people asking why), here are few more examples.

---

In C, the `==` operator is left-to-right associative and boolean is represented as 1 (true) and 0 (false), so the first `1 == 1` evaluates to `1` (true) and then you are evaluating the result of first expression with the second. You can try:

```
2 == 2 == 2 // => 0
```

Which in C, is evaluated as:

```
(2 == 2) == 2
1 == 2 // => 0
```

---

In Javascript, similarly to C, `==` is left to right associative. Let's try with 0 this time (although the same example from C would work as well):

```
0 == 0 == 0
false
```

Again:

```
0 == 0 == 0
true == 0 // => false
```

---

In Ruby `==` does not have associative properties, ie. it can't be used multiple times in single expression, so that expression can't be evaluated. Why that decision was made is a question for the author of the language. Further, Ruby doesn't define numeric 1 as a boolean, so `1 == true` evaluates to false.

The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49825687/1757831) states there are some "weird" cases in Ruby, but they all evaluate as expected:

```
(1 == 1) == 1
true == 1 # => false

1 == (1 == 1)
1 == true # => false

1 .== 1 == 1
(1 == 1) == 1
true == 1 # => false

false .== false == true
(false == false) == true
true == true # => true

false .== true == false
(false == true) == false
false == false # => true

true .== false == false
(true == false) == false
false == false # => true

false .== false == false
(false == false) == false
true == false # => false

true .== true == false
(true == true) == false
true == false # => false
```