# How do Ruby operators have normal precedence if they're also methods?

Tags: ruby

Ruby's operators, like `+` or `*`, follow the order of precedence as in mathematics when used in the syntax-sugar form. In the following, `*` is called before `+`:

```
# Syntax-sugar form
5 + 5 * 2 # => 15
```

In the non-syntax-sugar form, the methods follow the linear order in which they are written. In the following, `+` is called before `*`:

```
# Non-syntax-sugar form
5.+(5).*(2) # => 20
```

Methods that I define, like the `+` method as follows, work both with and without the syntax-sugar form:

```
class WackyInt
  attr_reader :value     

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def +(other)
    WackyInt.new(value + other.value)
  end
end

ONE = WackyInt.new 1
FIVE = WackyInt.new 5

# As operators
ONE + FIVE # => #<WackyInt @number=-4>
# As methods
ONE.+(FIVE) # => #<WackyInt @number=-4>
```

The defined operators follow the respective order of precedence both in the syntax-sugar form and the non-syntax-sugar form.

How can Ruby parse this?

Comment: `#<WackyInt @number=6>`, not `#<WackyInt @number=-4>`

Comment: I guess the operators are recognized by Ruby's parser which turns them into method calls (according to their precedence). Whether the receiver is a literal, a variable, a method call or a constant doesn't really matter.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, exactly -- *"How is Ruby able to parse this?"* Are you asking how does a parser work? Are you asking where _exactly_ in the parser is responsible for interpreting `+` operations? Are you surprised by ruby's behaviour here; is there something about it you don't understand?

Comment: I feel brackets are influencing the behaviour. Try define also * as method in WacyInt class. Then: `# As operators
p FIVE + TWO * FIVE # => @value=15
p 5 + 2 * 5 # => 15
# As methods
p FIVE.+(TWO).*(FIVE) # => @value=35
p 5.+(2).*(5) # => 35
# As methods no brackets
p FIVE.+TWO.*FIVE # => # @value=15
p 5.+2.*5 # => 15`
Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159938/5239030)

Comment: The MRI parser is over 11,000 lines of code... [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/8cd5ccdc7fc38d271ebe33c63d64f2950a97aea0/parse.y#L7937-L7945) is a relevant section in relation to handling the `+` character. Does that answer your question?!

Comment: _'So, I know that Ruby's operators – like almost all other programming languages – follow the order of operations'_. I know what you mean, but I don't think it's clear what you're talking about here. Needs clarification.

Comment: You need to also define `*` and show order or precedence in complex cases in order to show your point with overwritten methods.

Answer (score 0):

Tokenizing, parsing, and assigning computational precedence is separated from calling and executing the methods. What you can overwrite is what is done when a method is called. That does not change how a Ruby code is tokeninzed or parsed, and hence computational precedence is not affected by that.